# How save b64 as pdf?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I got a bytes from API and I convert to b64, I want to save in the iPhone the pdf but when I call my function I only get this : file:///Applications/Demos/yourFileName.pdf

I need to save a file as pdf in the iPhone Downloads folder which comes from a B64 String

What's  missing in my code ?

```
func saveBase64StringToPDF(_ base64String: String) {

    guard
        var documentsURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .allApplicationsDirectory, in:.allDomainsMask)).last,
        let convertedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)
        else {
            debugPrint("Error")
        return
    }

    documentsURL.appendPathComponent("yourFileName.pdf")

    do {
        try convertedData.write(to: documentsURL, options: .atomic)
        pdfURL = documentsURL
        debugPrint("Aquí se guarda el pdf??")

    } catch {
        debugPrint("Error")
    }


    debugPrint(documentsURL)
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. `debugPrint(documentsURL)` prints the path of file in the Xcode debugger. So `file:///Applications/Demos/yourFileName.pdf` is the expected output. But it seems you are expecting something else. Can you better describe what you expect to happen?

Comment: @Codo Ok thanks, I need to save a file as pdf  in the iPhone Downloads folder which comes from a B64 String

Comment: Your code converts the base64String passed into it to Data and attempts to write that content to a file "yourFileName.pdf" in the app's documents directory. If it succeeds, it prints the path to that file to the debug console. (So it sounds like it's working, and you should find the file at that location.) There isn't a "downloads" directory on iOS, exactly.

Comment: @DuncanC Ok thanks, do you know how can I put it in downloads directory on iOS or is that impossible ?

Comment: If it should go to the *Download* directory, use `downloadsDirectory` instead of `allApplicationsDirectory`.

Comment: @Codo I got this output: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/5B3E746E-EE27-4203-A79A-BA5F7E175440/Downloads/yourFileName.pdf`

   I want to save in the iPhone Downloads directory

Comment: That **is** a path to your app's downloads directory. iOS app's access to the file system is "sandboxed." Each app gets its own view into the different directories like `Documents` and `Downloads` and that prefix is the path to **your** app's directories.

Comment: The document has most likely been saved in the Downloads folder. So what is the problem? Isn't it what you want to achieve? What else do you expect to happen?